# Build Windows DllMain DLL with CMake

Tags: cmake, clion

I have a question similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490489/create-a-windows-shared-library-with-dllmain-function-mingw-cmake). I am trying to compile a DLL for windows similar to how Visual Studio would, except with CLion and CMake. I've tried the answer in the question, as well as the steps shown [here](https://cmake.org/Wiki/BuildingWinDLL), but I still get an error while injecting.

My dll code is very simple, a similar dll compiled in visual studio works fine:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void hello() {
    AllocConsole();
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
}

bool __stdcall DllMain(HMODULE /*module*/, DWORD reason, LPVOID /*reserved*/) {
    if (reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) hello();
    return true;
}
```

Also, here's what I tried in `CMakeLists.txt`: **sorry, there should have been a space between PROJECT_NAME and MODULE**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(PROJECT_NAME)
include (GenerateExportHeader)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_library(PROJECT_NAME MODULE main.cpp)
set_target_properties(PROJECT_NAME PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-m32" LINK_FLAGS "-m32")
GENERATE_EXPORT_HEADER(PROJECT_NAME
    BASE_NAME PROJECT_NAME
    EXPORT_MACRO_NAME PROJECT_NAME_EXPORT
    EXPORT_FILE_NAME PROJECT_NAME_Export.h
    STATIC_DEFINE PROJECT_NAME_BUILT_AS_STATIC)
```

Comment: Try to add SHARED to your add_library call, i.e. `add_library(PROJECT_NAMEMODULE SHARED main.cpp)`, because otherwise a static library is created.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Add the `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` variable to CMake's cache as a boolean value then check it. This will modify the behaviour of the `add_library` command to make a shared library i.e. a DLL file on Windows.
2. Explicitly create the library as shared: `add_library(PROJECT_NAMEMODULE SHARED main.cpp)`

`BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` variable documentation: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/variable/BUILD_SHARED_LIBS.html